# fit method of Imputer throwing missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' error

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-3.6, spyder

I am trying to address missing data problem during Data Preprocessing stage and had been following a udemy tutorial religiously.

This is my Dataset "Data.csv"

```
Country Age Salary  Purchased
France  44  72000   No
Spain   27  48000   Yes
Germany 30  54000   No
Spain   38  61000   No
Germany 40          Yes
France  35  58000   Yes
Spain       52000   No
France  48  79000   Yes
Germany 50  83000   No
France  37  67000   Yes
```

Here is the entire code.

```
    # Data Preprocessing

    #Importing Libraries

    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
    X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
    Y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

    # Taking care of missing data

    from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
    imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)

    #This line below throws the error
    imputer = Imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
    X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

The above code runs perfectly fine in the tutorial video however When i run the above code i get the following error:

```
**imputer = Imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-dddb27392326>", line 1, in <module>
    imputer = Imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'**
```

I am using the following specs:

OS : Win 8.1 tutorial had a MAC
IDE : Spyder 3.2.8
Python 3.6

Can somebody help me debug this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using sklearn version `0.19.1`. So there is an error in the code that you are calling the class method `Imputer.fit` instead of the instance method `imputer.fit` since `imputer` is the instance of `Imputer` in your code. Also you can use [fit_transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.fit_transform) method of `Imputer` to fit and transform the data in one go like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

# Taking care of missing data
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = "NaN", strategy = "mean", axis = 0)

X[:, 1:3] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

This changes the array `X` to

```
array([['France', 44.0, 72000.0],
   ['Spain', 27.0, 48000.0],
   ['Germany', 30.0, 54000.0],
   ['Spain', 38.0, 61000.0],
   ['Germany', 40.0, 63777.77777777778],
   ['France', 35.0, 58000.0],
   ['Spain', 38.77777777777778, 52000.0],
   ['France', 48.0, 79000.0],
   ['Germany', 50.0, 83000.0],
   ['France', 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)
```

As a side note, avoid naming the class instances with the same name as the class itself. I haven't change the name in my answer to point out the error in the code.

Comment: Your fit_transform() method did the trick but from what i have read fit_transform() combines calculation of mean and standard deviation from the training set and implicitly applies it on the same data set both of these functions are performed saperately by fit() and transform(). So if i need the fit from a different dataset to transform a different dataset fit_transform() wouldn't work. Am i getting this correctly?

Comment: Yes you are correct in assuming that.In that case use fit() and transform() function separately. If my answer helped you, can you please mark it as the correct one :)